# nodejs - upgrade to v20.11.0 LTS causes ETIMEDOUT error. What am I missing here?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, nvm

Minimal repro:

(I'm using NVM)

```sh
nvm install 19
> v19.9.0 is already installed.
> Now using node v19.9.0 (npm v9.6.3)

node -e "fetch('https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com').then(console.log)"

# (Expected response printed - it's a 400 Bad Request but that's what I'm expecting)

nvm install 20
> v20.11.0 is already installed.
> Now using node v20.11.0 (npm v10.2.4)

node -e "fetch('https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com').then(console.log)"

node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12344
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
          ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12344:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: AggregateError
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1177:5)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    [errors]: [
      Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.250.135.206:443
          at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1685:38)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -60,
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '34.250.135.206',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a05:d018:478:8a02:e0d0:7e78:bd7d:4728:443 - Local (:::51638)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1176:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -65,
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2a05:d018:478:8a02:e0d0:7e78:bd7d:4728',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.214.117.110:443
          at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1685:38)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -60,
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '52.214.117.110',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a05:d018:478:8a02:678f:9535:cb47:2ee6:443 - Local (:::51640)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1176:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -65,
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2a05:d018:478:8a02:678f:9535:cb47:2ee6',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.249.186.200:443
          at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1685:38)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -60,
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '34.249.186.200',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a05:d018:478:8a01:334e:2b03:ab65:ce82:443 - Local (:::51642)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1176:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -65,
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2a05:d018:478:8a01:334e:2b03:ab65:ce82',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.249.1.20:443
          at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1685:38)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -60,
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '34.249.1.20',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a05:d018:478:8a00:6490:459:4360:76bb:443 - Local (:::51644)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1176:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -65,
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2a05:d018:478:8a00:6490:459:4360:76bb',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 99.81.187.216:443
          at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1685:38)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -60,
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '99.81.187.216',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a05:d018:478:8a01:45c0:74e0:2a38:fe7c:443 - Local (:::51646)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1176:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -65,
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2a05:d018:478:8a01:45c0:74e0:2a38:fe7c',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.214.225.17:443
          at createConnectionError (node:net:1634:14)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1685:38)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -60,
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '52.214.225.17',
        port: 443
      },
      Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2a05:d018:478:8a00:28f7:5197:f348:603d:443 - Local (:::51648)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1176:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -65,
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2a05:d018:478:8a00:28f7:5197:f348:603d',
        port: 443
      }
    ]
  }
}

Node.js v20.11.0
```

What changed between 19 & 20 that I'm failing to find?

**Edit**

New information since posted, I've found that I can make the call work with Node 20 and above if I disable the DNS resolution settings in my vpn application (Tailscale). It makes sense to blame DNS (it's always DNS), but I am still puzzled why it would only be an issue between Node 19 and 20.

Comment: https://isitdns.com/